# Multiple nested borders with rounded corners. How to?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'd like to display a content enclosed by multiple borders of different colors and with rounded corners. I experimented with corner radius but could never get perfect corners (i.e. adjacent to corners of a parent border) on nested borders. What is the recommended practice in this case, if any?
The following is what I tried:

```
<Border Grid.Row="1"  Grid.Column="1" CornerRadius="3" BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="#FAFAFA"Background="#FAFAFA" Margin="40,40,40,40" Padding="0">
        <Border.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect Color="#1f40618c" />
        </Border.Effect>
        <StackPanel>
            <Border CornerRadius="3" BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="#696B6D" Background="#696B6D"  Margin="0" Padding="0" >
                <Border CornerRadius="2.3" BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="0" Padding="32,32,32,16" Background="#102F8C">
                    <Grid />
                </Border>
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take into account that the `BorderThickness` adds to the total width or height of a Border control. You can think of it as if half of the border line lies inside the control and half lies outside. On the other hand the `CornerRadius` is given relative to the center of the border line.

Consequently the difference between the inner and outer radius should be equal to the sum of half of both BorderThicknesses (plus perhaps the outer `Padding` and the inner `Margin`).

With your nested borders that have a `BorderThickness` of 3 each and an outer `CornerRadius` of also 3 that would result in an inner `CornerRadius` of 0.

You may simply set the inner `CornerRadius` to some sensible value and add 3 to that value for the outer one:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="6">
    <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="3">

    </Border>
</Border>
```