# Rounded Corners in UserControl not showing

Tags: wpf, user-controls, rounded-corners

I am trying to get my UserControl to display rounded corners.

This is my markup:

```
<Border CornerRadius="10" Padding="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
            <RowDefinition Height="25" />
            <RowDefinition Height="25" />
            <RowDefinition Height="25" />
            <RowDefinition Height="25" />
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="220" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="{StaticResource NavyBlueGround}" />
        </Grid.Background>
        <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"  Style="{StaticResource GelTitle}"   Content="Customer Search" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource GelCaption}"  Content="Enter Customer First Name" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
        <TextBox  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Name="txtForeName"  Background="White" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource GelCaption}"  Content="Enter Customer Last Name" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
        <TextBox Name="txtSurname" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4"  FontSize="14" Text="hello" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
        <Button Name="btnCustomerSearch" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" Style="{StaticResource GelButton}" Content="Search" Click="btnCustomerSearch_Click" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

and this is what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Add a non-transparent background to your border and you'll start seeing the rounded corners.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using the background for your Grid, use it for your border.

```
<Border CornerRadius="10" Padding="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
    <Border.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{StaticResource NavyBlueGround}" />
    </Border.Background>
```

**EDIT:** The reason for this problem is that a border (when padding=5) sets the margins of its child 5 pixels in. also defining CornerRadius sets the margins of grid in even further.

So the bounds of Grid (and its background) are not where the rounded corners occur.

Comment: Looks promising I shall try as soon as I get back. Thanks

Comment: Great answer and so simple.  I profess I am still getting used to WPF but the more I learn the more I prefer it over WinForms. Thanks

Comment: Wow, I just spent about one hour searching for THIS solution. Thank you so much, I was going mad!

Answer (score 2):

You must have something else going on.  I pasted your code into a new project with UserControl and it renders fine.

[image: Example Image]

Can you provide more detail if a new project does not work the same for you, and compare differences to help troubleshoot?

Comment: Hi, thanks for all you time in this. I have accepted a simpler answer. Regarding your theory I would tend to agree with you.  I am using styles for the inner elements but in no way do they affect the borders so it must just be the 'thing' of using styles for inner elements that 'could' affect the outer borders.  The answer I accepted eliminates this ;quandary' thanks so much for you comment/answer

Comment: It renders fine for you because you also have set the background for the border :)